# is select() blocking or non-blocking call

Tags: linux, sockets, blocking, nonblocking

Is it fair to say that `select()` is non-blocking when it passes `struct timeval` argument with timeout value? And when that argument is NULL, it is blocking.

Answer (score 8):

> Is is fair to say that select() is non-blocking when it passes struct timeval argument with timeout value?

No. It is waiting in this case until either one of the selected file descriptors get ready or the timeout is reached. This "waiting" is clearly blocking.

The only case where this is non-blocking is if the timeout is 0, i.e. `tv_sec` and `tv_usec` of the given `timeval` are set to 0.